# counting unique and duplicate values in multiple columns in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

[image: Supervisor and Project Names]

i have these values in a table in PowerBI
What i need to do is to create a visualization showing the number of projects that a person shows up in,

eg, alan is doing 2 projects and peter is doing 3, so there should be a no.of project by staff name kind of visualization.

I tried merge tables, unpivot column but nothing works.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot will do what you need. Get your table into the Query Editor, select the first column and unpivot the other columns. That will get you a simple flat table like the one below, from which you can then perform aggregates like count per person. The screenshot shows an Excel pivot table, but of course you can use a Power BI chart.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I did as you suggested, with the exception of performing aggregates. I use the project count and names as a stacked bar chart and that did the trick.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the post as the answer to finish up here.

Comment: @teylyn Please look at here to know [how does accepting an answer works][1]  [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @teylyn And here [What should I do when someone answers my question?][1] [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @GingerHead I'm not the one who asked the question and I don't need the education. The [Tour] also provides good info for new users.